# replace all images in an XML file

Tags: xml, regex, wordpress, replace

I have import all my wordpress content and now I want to replace all images with a placeholder image. The most obvious way I think is to search and replace all the images. I try to do it manually but the file is big enougth to make me rethinking this.

This is an example of wordpress exported XML file: https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/demo/theme-unit-test-data.xml

I would like to replace all images url with placehold.it url (http://placehold.it/)

I am using sublime text editor, is there a any regex to search all the image url on a XML file? I am really not very good with regex..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include a short example of intended input/output as well as what you've tried?

Comment: Are you going to keep the URLs of the images, just in case, or do you just want to dump them?

Comment: No, I don't want to keep them, I want to replace all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple regex to replace all image `src` attributes with some placeholder text would be:

Search for:

```
<img (.*?)src=".*?"
```

Replace with:

```
<img $1src="http://example.com"
```

If you want to use the placeholder URL, you could do:

```
<img (.*?)src=".*?"(.*?)width="(\d+)" height="(\d+)"
```

Replace with:

```
<img $1src="http://placehold.it/$3x$4"$2width="$3" height="$4"
```

Explanation:

- `.*?` means 0 or more characters
- `\d+` means 1 or more digits
- `(` and `)` capture the contents of the parentheses and save it to `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.
- `<img (.*?)src` captures any characters between `<img` and `src` and saves them in `$1` -- so if there is a class attribute, an ID, anything like that--it will be saved as `$1`. `.*?` can also match nothing, so `$1` can also be blank.
- `width="(\d+)"` captures the digits that give the image width, and saves them to `$3` (since it's the third set of parentheses in that regular expression).

Answer (score 1):

regex:

```
(\<img\s+.*?src\s*=\s*)(?|"(.*?)"|\'(.*?)\')(.*?\/?\>)
```

replacement:

```
$1"http://placehold.it/"$3
```

If your editor supports regex search and replace then use above, else in PHP:

```
$string = preg_replace( '/(\<img\s+.*?src\s*=\s*)(?|"(.*?)"|\'(.*?)\')(.*?\/?\>)/is', '$1"http://placehold.it/"$3', $string );
```